# compact set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

i am studing the (Schrodinger operator) but this question is in topology:

i found in a course that this set :

$DS_\alpha(\lambda,\gamma)=\{\beta\in\mathbb{R}| \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\},\forall l\in\mathbb{Z} : |\beta-k\alpha-l|\geq\frac{\lambda^{-1}}{|k|^\gamma}\}$

is compact , so how to prove that it is compact?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

A compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set which is closed and bounded.

The closed part is easy -- arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed, and for each $k,l$, the set $\{\beta: |\beta - k \alpha - l| \geq \lambda^{-1} / |k|^\gamma\}$ is closed (write it as the union of two closed intervals, which results in a closed set.

Now, show that the resultant set is bounded, i.e. there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $r< \infty$, such that $D S_{\alpha} (\lambda, \gamma) $ is contained in the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. I'll leave you to try this part.

Comment: tkank you for unswering but for the first part , why it will be the intersection of closed set because i think that it will be an intersection of intervalls written like that  $[q,+\infty[ $ and $ ]-\infty,-q]$ ?? and this is not closed i think

Comment: Fix $k, l$. Then $\{\beta: |\beta - k \alpha - l| \geq \lambda^{-1} / |k|^\gamma\}$ will be $\beta \geq c_1$ or $\beta \leq c_2$ for some $c_1,c_2$. These are two closed intervals, so their union is closed. Then, its a basic fact of a topology (in fact, part of the definition) that the intersection of arbitrarily many closed sets is closed.

Comment: thanks, but the second part doesn t seem to be easy :)!